# How to solve this equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac {md^2x} {(dt)^2}=x$$ where **m** is some constant number. I tried to find **x** by simple actions. But it is not right. So,how to solve this equation?

Comment: Do you mean $m\frac {d^2x} {dt^2}=x$

Comment: For problems of the form $$a\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+b\frac{dx}{dt}+cx+d=0$$ we use the substitution $x=p\cdot e^{qt}+\frac{1-d}c$ and solve for $p,q$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left(e^{kt}\right)=k^2e^{kt}$$

Answer (score 0):

Is it easier for you if $m=1$? What function $x(t)$, differentiated twice, is equal to itself?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let multiply both sides by $2\frac{dx}{dt}$,

$2mx'x''=2xx'$ which gives after integration,

$m(\frac{dx}{dt})^2=x^2+C$

and

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\pm \frac{1}{m}\sqrt{x^2+C}$

you can find $x(t)$ by the change

$x=\sqrt{C }sh(u)$ or $x= \sqrt{-C} ch(u)$.

Comment: I think OP means the second derivative, not the square of the first derivative

Comment: @MPW Which square ?